# Неправильно вычисляется произведение ряда

Tags: c++, ряды

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double x, sm = 1;
   int n;
   cin >> n >> x;
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      sm *= (i/(i+1) - pow(cos(abs(x)), i));
   }
   cout.precision(6);
   cout << fixed << sm << endl;
}
```

Я просто не понимаю, что у меня не так с кодом, чего только не перепробовал.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код - **текстом**, а не картинкой. И как вы узнали, что результат неверен?

Comment: Впрочем, всё ясно - целочисленное деление

Comment: Пример на скрине

Comment: А понял, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Целочисленное деление даёт ноль, нужно заставить выполняться вещественное. При этом индекс цикла не нужно делать вещественным.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   sm *= (double(i)/(i+1) - pow(cos(abs(x)), i));
}
```

Кроме того, можно сделать небольшую оптимизацию - не потребуется на каждом шаге вычислять косинус и степень (тяжёлые операции)

```
double cospow = cosx = cos(abs(x);

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   sm *= (double(i)/(i+1) - cospow);
   cospow *= cosx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double x, sm = 1;
   int n;
   cin >> n >> x;
   for (double i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      sm *= (i/(i+1) - pow(cos(abs(x)), i));
   }
   cout.precision(6);
   cout << fixed << sm << endl;
}
```

Деление должно быть не целочисленным

Comment: старайтесь давать чуть более развернутые ответы и не обходиться одним лишь кодом.

Comment: Нет, лучше не менять тип счётчика цикла на `double` - из-за точности операций с плавающей точкой у вас иногда может случиться, что последняя итерация цикла не будет выполнена. Вместо этого можно либо по месту привести `i` к `double`, либо написать `i/(i+1.0)`.